# Is this the right way to RegisterDecorator when some types have no implementation?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, fluentvalidation, simple-injector

Using simple injector [with the command pattern described here](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91). Most commands have companion classes that implement fluent validation's `AbstractValidator<TCommand>`, which means they also implement FV `IValidator<TCommand>`. However it doesn't always make sense to have a validator implementation for every command.

As far as I can tell, the command decorator implementation cannot take `IValidator<TCommand>` as a constructor arg unless every `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` has a corresponding FV.`IValidator<TCommand>`. I tried the following:

```
public class FluentValidationCommandDecorator<TCommand> 
    : IHandleCommands<TCommand>
{
    public FluentValidationCommandDecorator(IHandleCommands<TCommand> decorated
        , IValidator<TCommand> validator
    )
    {
        _decorated = decorated;
        _validator = validator;
    }
    ...
}
...
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IValidator<>), assemblies);
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IHandleCommands<>),
    typeof(FluentValidationCommandDecorator<>),
    context =>
    {
        var validatorType =
            typeof (IValidator<>).MakeGenericType(
                context.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments());
        if (container.GetRegistration(validatorType) == null)
            return false;
        return true;
    });
```

Unit tests that run `Container.Verify()` once, pass. Unit tests that run `Container.Verify()` more than once, fail from an `InvalidOperationException` on the second invocation:

```
The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type 
IValidator<SomeCommandThatHasNoValidatorImplementation> failed. Object reference
not set to  an instance of an object.
```

The following works, by taking the `Container` as an argument:

```
public class FluentValidationCommandDecorator<TCommand> 
    : IHandleCommands<TCommand>
{
    private readonly IHandleCommands<TCommand> _decorated;
    private readonly Container _container;

    public FluentValidationCommandDecorator(Container container
        , IHandleCommands<TCommand> decorated
    )
    {
        _container = container;
        _decorated = decorated;
    }

    public void Handle(TCommand command)
    {
        IValidator<TCommand> validator = null;
        if (_container.GetRegistration(typeof(IValidator<TCommand>)) != null)
            validator = _container.GetInstance<IValidator<TCommand>>();

        if (validator != null) validator.ValidateAndThrow(command);

        _decorated.Handle(command);
    }
}
...
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IValidator<>), assemblies);
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IHandleCommands<>),
    typeof(FluentValidationCommandDecorator<>));
```

If this class didn't have to take a dependency on Simple Injector, I could move it into the domain project. The domain already takes a dependency on FluentValidation.net so that domain validity can be unit tested. I think this decorator belongs in the domain, but neither it nor its unit test project takes a dependency on simpleinjector (or should have to, since the domain is not the composition root).

**Is there a way to tell simpleinjector to only decorate a `CommandHandler<TCommand>` instance with a `FluentValidationCommandDecorator<TCommand>` if there is an implementation registered for `IValidator<TCommand>`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is unregistered type resolution, to map missing types to a default implementation. Or in other words, you need to use the `RegisterOpenGeneric` method:

```cs
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IValidator<>), 
    typeof(NullValidator<>));
```

Now you need to define a `NullValidator<T>` that implements `IValidator<T>` with an empty / default implementation.

When you do this every time a certain (unregistered) `IValidator<T>` is requested, a new instance of `NullValidator<T>` will be returned. It will not override types that are registered using `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric`, since those types are explictly registered.

When the `NullValidator<T>` implementation is thread-safe (which will usually be the case with a empty implementation), you can optimize construction by registering them as singleton:

```cs
container.RegisterSingleOpenGeneric(typeof(IValidator<>), 
    typeof(NullValidator<>));
```

You can read more information in the wiki: [Registration of open generic types](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Advanced-scenarios&referringTitle=Documentation#Registration_Of_Open_Generic_Types)

Comment: Unregistered type resolution, got it. It seems that the `NullValidator<>` does belong in the same lib with simpleinjector, but this allows me to move the decorator out. My NullValidator just inherits fluentvalidation's `AbstractValidator<T>` -- no constructors, fields, nothing -- and from what I can tell is thread-safe, so am registering it as a single.

Comment: Another side-effect of this seems to be that the commands which DO have `IValidator<TCommand>` implementations are decorated twice -- once with the real implementation, and once with the NullValidator. Is this to be expected?

Comment: I'm not sure why you should have the `NullValidator` to be a decorator. I'm not sure what you are doing. Can you update your question with your current code and configuration?

Comment: You are right, the commands with specific validators are not being decorated twice. I have 2 similarly named commands, 1 with a specific validator, and 1 without. I was misreading the debugger watch, and thought that 1 command was being decorated twice, when in fact the command decorated with the NullValidator did not have the same TCommand type as the one being decorated with a specific validator. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Visual Studio and .NET displays generic types in an awful format. This bugs me a lot, and that's why I display generic type names in a more friendly format in the Simple Injector exception messages.